# The probability of the intersection is less than the square root of the product of the probability

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In my graduate probability and measure course, I ran into a problem that asks me to proof that

$$ P (A\cap B)\leq \sqrt{P(A) P (B)} $$
I tried a loot and I didn't manage to proof the statement. I use "Olav Kallenberg - Foundations of Modern Probability"
as my source material. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Isn't this trivial? $$P(A\cap B)\le\min\{P(A),P(B)\}\le\sqrt{P(A)P(B)}$$ What am I missing?

Comment: thanks for helping.  I processed it in a wrong way, I tried to use the measure hypotheses, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposed inequality is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
[\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)]^{2} \leq \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)
\end{align*}

which is true indeed.

Since $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\cap B\subseteq B$, the monotonicity of the probability measure implies that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\leq \mathbb{P}(A)\\\\
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\leq \mathbb{P}(B)
\end{cases} \Rightarrow [\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)]^{2} \leq \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B) \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\leq \sqrt{\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)}
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks a loot, I feel stupid now, I over think of it and I messed the obvious. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome ! I am glad to help.